# Calculate Days between changes in History Object

Tags: apex, reporting

I'm tracking changes to a field called Status, i have a requirement to produce a report that shows the number of days between a change from one status to another specific status. This can happen a number of times for a particular record so i can't just create a couple of date fields on the object to capture these changes.

Not possible in report builder so does anyone have any thoughts about how to go about this in apex?

Cheers

Comment: `daysBetween` method of the Date object? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Comment: its more the bit about getting the relevant records together rather than the actual date calculation e.g. to form this sort of structure from the history object:

Comment: ID : Edit Date1 : Old Value 1 : New Value 1 : Edit Date 2 : Old Value 2 : New Value 2 : Days between 1 & 2

Comment: I guess you'll need a related list of records for that object and a trigger that will create a new record whenever the value have changed on the Status field. Then you'll be able to report on children of the History Object. Is that what you're after? I can provide code examples of how to achieve that if you require.

Comment: trying to avoid creating an additional custom object to achieve this, particularly given SF's rather stingey custom obj limits...